# I'm having this issue with a 3D platform not pushing my player but moves right through it

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

I am able to have my player walk on the platform and have the player move with the platform, but when I am walking into the platform, while the platform is moving, from any side my player is able to walk through it. I am moving the platform by setting its position with a time value inside a Sin function. The gameObject 'go' is a reference to a trigger object that is part of the platform which I use to move the player when touching the trigger the same speed as the platform, but does not working all the time.

Here is the platform code:

```
public class OscilateX : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float startX;
    private float startZ;
    private float val;
    public float speed;
    public float distance;
    public GameObject go;

    public List<GameObject> contacts = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startX = transform.position.x;
        startZ = transform.position.z;
        val = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float motion = transform.position.x;
        val += .01f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(startX + Mathf.Sin(val * speed) * distance, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        motion = transform.position.x - motion;
        foreach(GameObject a in contacts)
        {
            if((motion - a.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude) / (a.transform.position.x - transform.position.x) > 0) a.transform.position = new Vector3(a.transform.position.x + motion, a.transform.position.y, a.transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried finding info on this on Youtube and have looked this problem up on stack overflow, but have not found anything specific enough that can help me with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I had to do was make the Collision Detection for both the platform and the player "Continuous Dynamic"